# Holder condition and differentability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Prove that if a function is $C^2$ on a closed interval, then it satisfies holder condition of order 2.

Thanks

Comment: The only functions satisfying a Holder condition of order $>1$ are the constants.

Comment: This can't be true. At any point where derivative doesn't vanish, the function fails Holder condition of order 2. It's because $\delta x$ is large compared to $(\delta x)^2$ for small $\delta x$.

Comment: @Vim sorry I didn't understand you

Comment: @user115608 note that $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+\frac12f''(x)h^2+o(h^2)$$

Comment: @Vim would you please explain more?

Comment: What do you mean by Holder condition of order 2? If you mean there exists $C$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^2$ for all $x,y$ in an interval, then the function must be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to assume $C^2$ or even differentiability. If $a>1$ and $|f(y)-f(x)|\le C|y-x|^a$ for all $x,y\in [a,b],$ then $f$ is constant on $[a,b].$ Proof: Suppose $a<x<b.$ Then

$$\left |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \right| = \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|} \le \frac{C|h|^{a}}{|h|} = C|h|^{a-1}.$$

Because $a-1>0,$ the limit of the above as $h\to 0$ is $0.$ Therefore $f'(x)=0.$ The same argument can be made for one-sided derivatives at the endpoints. Thus $f'(x)= 0$ for all $x\in [a,b],$  which implies $f$ is constant.